# invoking aws lambda functions locally with node aws sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am fairly new running lambda functions locally with sam.
I have this project setup where a "node express app" acts as an middleware between internet (api gateway) and other lambda functions.

based on resource path another lambda function is invoked.

invocation code block:

```
const { Lambda } = require ("@aws-sdk/client-lambda");
const client = new Lambda({region: "eu-central-1"});
const input = { 
                FunctionName: "My-func",
                InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
                Payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
            };
client.invoke(input);
```

`My-func` is a java based lambda function .

This setup works all fine on lambda but when running locally there are few issues that i am unable to fix. following the below setup.

i am using sam to run my lambda functions.
running my java function (My-func) as `sam local start-lambda -t my-func.yaml` which runs the lambda on 127.0.0.1:3001.

Now i am trying to invoke this function from my nodejs app, i read some github issues from aws sdk repo to specify the endpoint in lambda client initialization config like

```
const client = new Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31', endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/' });
```

and use the same code as above to invoke the function. but this does not work fails with error:
 `'$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 } (net.js:1144:16) {   ERROR   Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3001`

please help me in figuring out how to invoke one lambda function from another running locally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/260

Comment: @jarmod, cool that works. 
but i need to start lambda with host 0.0.0.0 .
Thanks for the reference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running my lambda function as `sam local start-lambda -t my-func.yaml --host 0.0.0.0` and modify the lambda config to use dockers ip `172.17.0.1` as endpoint  worked `const client = new Lambda({region: "eu-central-1", apiVersion: '2015-03-31', endpoint: 'http://172.17.0.1:3001' });`